# Valuing a call option that is issued today, exercisable after 2 years from the issue date and expires 3 years after the issue date

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options

if we assume:

Current price: $0.25

Exercise price: $0.25

life: 3 years

Risk free rate p.a: 0.2%

volatility p.a: 85%

The option cannot be exercised within the first 2 years, after 2 years, it is exercisable at anytime until expiry.

How would you value this? I initially thought a Binomial tree but then thought that BSM would probably be a close enough proxy given it assumes exercise at expiry.

Thoughts?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a 2x5 forward starting option of American flavor. You can check the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_start_option) 
 or [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/28133/) or [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59952/) threads as a starting point. AFAIK the crucial point with these options is to determine an expectation for the asset price after 2 years; other than that Black-Scholes should suffice for Europeans (giving you at least a boundary for the American), but I'm not proficient enough to give a full answer

Comment: This is not a forward start option because the strike price is known on the issue date. This is a simple american call that can be exercised at any time between year 2 and year 3. In the absence of dividends it is optimal to exercise in year 3, so it boils down to a simple 3 years european call that can be valued using BS.

Comment: It can also be priced using the Binomial method: check Hull 8th ed C15: Employee Stock Options section Valuation for the theory.